# Dynamic navigation items in Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to populate DrawerNavigator from response from an api. How can the drawer items be loaded dynamically?

Eg

```
    'someName1': { screen: (props) => <someView {...props} viewId='someId2' /> },
    'someName2': { screen: (props) => <someView {...props} viewId='someId2' /> },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved it-

In render method-

```
const Nav = DrawerNavigator(this.getNavItems(this.state.drawerSource.navItems));

        const AppNavigator = (StackNavigator(
            {
                Drawer: { screen: Nav },
            },
            {
                initialRouteName: "Drawer",
                headerMode: "none",
            })
        );

        return (<AppNavigator />);

getNavItems(navItems) {
    return navItems.reduce((routes, navItem) => {
        routes[navItem.id] = this.getNavItem(navItem);

        return routes;
    }, {});
}

getNavItem(navItem) {
    return {
        screen: (props) => <MyScreen {...props} id={navItem.id} />,
        navigationOptions: {
            ***any navigation properties
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of providing Screens directly to drawerComponent, provide a custom component for your drawermenu using the `contentComponent` as options to your `DrawerNavigator`. Then you can style and edit the drawerMenu anyway you want it. In that component, you can make an API call, get the list of menu items and load them in the component render method, which will be shown as the drawerMenu.

Note : You should make sure that you do not call this API very often, because if you do, for a while, user may get a blank drawerMenu until the API response is received. One way to handle this is to save the menu in Redux store and make the API call on the starting of the app, and have it stored/persisted in redux store.

I hope you found this answer helpful.

Comment: can you please clarify more, an example would be ideal, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use FlatList https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html in the drawer navigator and update the items with the correct props.

This link provides the boiler plate :  its about halfway down, search customdrawercontent and you should find it.
 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/

The following is done with arbitrary data from a flat list example and stuff part of my project, follows most of the boiler plate.

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DATA =
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];


function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  console.log('comminf from custom drawer', props)

  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        keyExtractor={data => data.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <DrawerItem label={item.title} onPress={()=> alert(item.id)}>

          </DrawerItem>
          )
        }}
        />
      <DrawerItem label="Help" onPress={() => alert('Link to help')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const newthing = "wtf how do i give my drawer stuff";


 function RoleNavigator () {

  //console.log('drawer user', userId)
  return (
  <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>

        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={WorkerView} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="BusinessView" component={BusinessView} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="SignOut" component={SignOutScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```